# How can you determine when a background task was started?

Tags: bash, job-control, process-monitoring

When surveying the output of `jobs` in `bash`, you'll often get a list like the following:

```
[root@csx-tzg-sac-01 ~]# jobs
[2]   Running                 ( sleep 600 && ls -lh ~ossadmin/*.iso ) &
[3]-  Running                 ( sleep 900 && ls -lh ~ossadmin/*.iso ) &
[4]+  Running                 ( sleep 900 && ls -lh ~ossadmin/*.iso ) &
```

Can you determine when a given job was started by the *jobid* (ie, not by looking at the pid from a place like `ps`)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the pid of the job from `jobs -l`, so that you don't have to *hunt* through `ps` output to find the job.  Is that why you were trying to avoid `ps`?

```
jobs -l | sed 's/^\[[0-9]*\][^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[^0-9].*/\1/' | xargs ps up
```

will work in bash and zsh.

If you're using zsh, then the `zsh/parameters` module provides the `$jobstates` array variable.  Eg:

```
% echo $jobstates[1]
running:-:14975=running
```

That can be easier to parse the pid from.  And if you're on a system with `/proc` then the timestamp on the proc dir will tell you when the process was started.

```
$ ls -ld /proc/$$
```

Comment: Bash has `jobs -p %1` to print the PID.

Comment: yes, I am trying to avoid `ps` because I may or may not be able to tie the pid to a start time (maybe there's a half dozen commands run that are otherwise identical but separated by seconds or minutes - picking which is which can be difficult/impossible)

Comment: Right, so my solution works for you: get the pid from jobs, then request the ps details for that one particular pid; you're no longer hunting for the process by name, just looking it up.